# Sass get parent or parent child

Tags: css, sass

There's a better way to do this?

```
.element{
    &-modifier{
        color: green;
    }

    &:hover{
        .element-modifier{
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

in this case if we change class ".element" on first line
then hover will stop working

i know one solution, but it does not solve the problem completely,

```
.element{
    $this: &;

    &-modifier{
        color: green;
    }

    &:hover{
        #{$this}-modifier{
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

in this case we need create a lot of variables ($this,$this2,$this3...)

so there's a better way to get parent or parents child?

Comment: If you could add 2 snippets that actually applies to the above way of thinking, where one shows _if we change class ".element" on first line
then hover will stop working_, we might be able to suggest something

Comment: You cannot get parent in css. Just siblings :)

Comment: @LaraBelle in css yes but we talking about sass (:

Comment: @DimaLutsik I've been using sass for a veeeery long time. Sass is just a css. Sass will always be compiled to CSS. So, if you can do it in SASS, you will be able to do it in CSS. Logic :)

Comment: @LaraBelle yes but in sass we have variables if statements and I thought that there should be something like parent variable..

Comment: @LGSon example = https://jsfiddle.net/di3orlive/zdtyw6zx/

Comment: why dont you declare as a function and just extend it where ever you want or call it as a function by passing the classname.

Comment: @Nirus not quite understand. can you add some example

Comment: What I mean is you cannot access parent element in child scope. Just tag me if you got some answer. I'm interested as well.

Comment: Sass is just a preprocessor. :)

Comment: @DimaLutsik see this https://jsfiddle.net/fmbd32bp/

Comment: @Nirus oh, like this, ok but if we have very big class that have a lot of childs  we need unique function for each, like with ($this) but much more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this logic useful?

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zdtyw6zx/1/)

SASS

```
.test{
    &-modifier{
        color: green;
    }

    &:hover &-modifier{
        color: red;        
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-modifier">test</div>
</div>
```

---

Here is a couple of more variants based on the given comments

```
.test{
    &-modifier{
        color: green;
    }

    &-modifier2{
        color: green;
    }

    &:hover &-modifier,
    &:hover &-modifier2
    {
        color: red;        
    }}
```

```
.test{
    &-modifier{
        color: green;
    }

    &-modifier2{
        color: green;
    }

    &:hover &-modifier2 {
        color: red;        
    }
}
```

```
.test{
    &-modifier{
        color: green;
    }

    &-modifier2{
        color: green;
    }

    &-modifier2:hover {
        color: red;        
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i' looking for. but in this case if we have one more (&-modifire2) we need to write again &:hover .... and I would like to write all in one :hover block (beautiful and clean code and so on (:)

Comment: @DimaLutsik Like these 2, which render the same hover effect, https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zdtyw6zx/2/ ...and this https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zdtyw6zx/3/ ...?

Comment: @DimaLutsik Either this https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zdtyw6zx/4/ ...or this https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zdtyw6zx/5/

Comment: @DimaLutsik Let me know if that helped

Comment: this is not exactly that i'm looking for, but i think there is no better solution for now...

Comment: @DimaLutsik When wanting something special, one often ends up with _not exactly what one was looking for_, so I hope it is at least better than what you had prior asking here :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution which does not introduce a variable for the class name but requires you to give up some nesting as you can only access the full parent selector.

```
.element{
    &-modifier{
        color: green;
    }

    &:hover &-modifier {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.element-modifier {
  color: green;
}
.element:hover .element-modifier {
  color: red;
}
```